# ImportError: cannot import name 'config' & 'module' object is not callable using PostgreSQL & Python

Tags: python, postgresql

Hey I am having trouble connecting to my PostgreSQL DB through Python. I am following [this tutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/connect/) However when I attempt to run the code I return the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/Coding/anybody/postgresqltest.py", line 2, in <module>
    from config import config
ImportError: cannot import name 'config'
[Finished in 0.201s]
```

However, I have pip installed config (I am using a virtual environment) and verified using `pip list`

When I remove `from config import config` and replace with just `import config` I receive this error:

`module' object is not callable [Finished in 0.127s]`

Here is the code I have written, I am a bit stuck on what to do next (the actual database I am connecting to isn't called test btw, this is a different one):

```
import psycopg2
from configparser import ConfigParser

def config(filename='database.ini', section='postgresql'):
    # create a parser
    parser = ConfigParser()
    # read config file
    parser.read(filename)

    # get section, default to postgresql
    db = {}
    if parser.has_section(section):
        params = parser.items(section)
        for param in params:
            db[param[0]] = param[1]
    else:
        raise Exception('Section {0} not found in the {1} file'.format(section, filename))

    return db

from config import config

def connect():
      conn = None

      try:
          params = config()

          print('Connecting to the PostgreSQL DB')
          conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)

          cur = conn.cursor()

          print('PostgreSQL database version:')
          cur.execute('Select version()')


          db_version = cur.fetchnone()
          print(db_version)

          cur.close()

      except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
          print(error)

      finally:
          if conn is not None:
              conn.close()
              print('Database connection closed.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect()
```

Comment: did you installed the `config` module? If not install [config](https://pypi.org/project/config/)

Comment: Yep still nothing.

Comment: did you installed the module? and you still getting the error?

Comment: that's right, could it be my virtualenv is incorrectly set up

Comment: The tutorial says "The config() function is placed in the config.py file".  But you seem to have just copied and pasted all the code into one file.  But I wouldn't make a module named 'config' anyway, since there is already a standard one with that name.

Comment: Thanks yes when I retried with the new file it did work. It does seem problematic to name a file config no?

Answer (score 0):

Put the config function into a separate .py file.

Answer (score 0):

actually you don't need the **config** module at all in case you have the DB connection parameters:

here's the code that worked for my connection to DB hosted by Elephant (https://api.elephantsql.com/):

```
    import psycopg2
    #from config import config

    conn = None

    conn = psycopg2.connect(
                    host="your DB host",
                    database="DB NAME",
                    user="USER NAME",
                    password="DB PASSWORD")

    try:


        # connect to the PostgreSQL server
        print('Connecting to the PostgreSQL database...')
        
        # create a cursor
        cur = conn.cursor()
        
    # execute a statement with cur.execute()
    # in this case we get the version


        print('PostgreSQL database version:')
        cur.execute('SELECT version()')

        # display the PostgreSQL database server version
        db_version = cur.fetchone()
        print(db_version)
       
        # close the communication with the PostgreSQL
        cur.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()
            print('Database connection closed.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

also, the docs by psycopg don't mention "config" module:
https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html